# SQL Statement Return April 4th, 4 years ago

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I go back to last April 4th (from today), minus 4 years, and return that date?

I could start by checking if today's date is before or after April 4 this year and go from there, but I would be interested to see different approaches to this issue.

This will be part of a larger select statement, so a self-contained SELECT or a function would be the best solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more clear, you want to retrieve the datetime of the 4th april 4 years ago via SQL? So if now would be 5th april, you want 4th april of 2008, if now would be 3rd april, you need 4th april of 2007?

Comment: I think you want a datetime such that it's the 4th April, and it's at least 4 years ago and strictly less than 5 years ago, correct?

Comment: Tim, @Damien - both correct, sorry I should have been more specific.  Need to be at least 4 years ago but less than 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any neater way of doing this - I normally fall back on my tried and true `DATEADD/DATEDIFF` pair to do date calculations, but I can't think of a way to take account of how far through the year we are neatly - so we get a `CASE` expression as well:

```
select DATEADD(year,
DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
- CASE WHEN DATEPART(month,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) IN (1,2,3) THEN 1
    WHEN DATEPART(month,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 4 AND
        DATEPART(day,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 4 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
,'19970404')
```

For testing particular dates to check edges conditions:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '20120403'
select DATEADD(year,
DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',@dt)
- CASE WHEN DATEPART(month,@dt) IN (1,2,3) THEN 1
    WHEN DATEPART(month,@dt) = 4 AND
        DATEPART(day,@dt) < 4 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
,'19970404')
```

---

If you just need 4th April of the year four years before the current year, then

```
DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, '20010101', @dt), '19970404')
```

will suffice.

Comment: I was going to suggest something clever with `DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR` but it quickly gets less clever when you have to factor in stupid leap years. :-)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for providing the test script too, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN SIGN(DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE(), STR(DATEPART(YY, GETDATE())) + '-04-04')) = 1
           THEN DATEADD(YY, -4, STR(DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()) - 1) + '-04-04')
         ELSE DATEADD(YY, -4, STR(DATEPART(YY, GETDATE())) + '-04-04')
       END;
```

Edit:
This checks whether the difference between the 4th of April and today is positive ('4/4 will be later this year') or zero/negative ('4/4 is today or before today') and returns the date according to that check.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()

select dateadd(day, 3, dateadd(month, 3, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, @date)-4, 0)))
```

Comment: That works if the OP wants 4th of April of the year four years before the current year, but not if they want 4th of April that is *at least* 4 years ago (consider dates in march, for instance).